# Excluding List of Figures / List of Tables from the Table of Contents (LaTex, report class)

Tags: table-of-contents

I am completely new to LaTeX, and I used the template provided by my school to write my dissertation. Now the dissertation is done, but there are bits and pieces of formatting issues I need to address. One of many is to remove items denoted in Roman numerals from the Table of Contents, which are List of Figures and List of Tables (see below).

[image: My ToC]

There are many posts about adding the LoF and LoT to the ToC, but not deleting them from the ToC (or if there is, I am having trouble finding it). What I have now is:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
...
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures  
\listoftables
```

How do I keep the LoF and LoT where they are now (i.e. right after the ToC), but remove them *from* the ToC?

Sorry if I didn't provide enough code for you to be able to see what's happening here - if so, please let me know. Thank you so much!!

=========== addition below ============

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xtab}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{guthesis} % Style file for dissertation

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{abstract}
This dissertation examines blah blah
\end{abstract}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures  
\listoftables  


\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\chapter{Introduction}
...

\end{document}
```

=================================

Comment: The package `titletoc` does not add (if at all) the LoF and Lot to the ToC by itself. Either you have some explicit `\addcontentsline`settings or using another package, which does this,e.g. `tocbibind`

Comment: Please add a compilable document that shows this issue!

Comment: If your school provides the template, they probably expect you to follow it.  Discuss any changes with your advisor.

Comment: Thank you, Christian, and John, for your comments. John, I already emailed the grad school asking why there are so many formatting revision requests when I used the template. I haven't heard back from them. Christian, I just added all the preamble commands above so that you can see better hopefully.. I checked for \addcontentsline, but there is no such setting anywhere in the template (nor I added it). Is it possible that the school template embeds some type of weird setting that made this happen?

Comment: @Sinead-d: I can't compile this, due to lacking of `guthesis` -- where can we find this? (I suspect that file is the villain!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `guthesis` is `Georgetown University Thesis` package file, using `\pseudochapter{\listfigurename}` and `\pseudochapter{\listtablename}` for adding the `LoF` and `LoT` to the ToC.

(The `guthesis.sty` can be found in a `.zip` bundle here: [GU Thesis LaTeX template](https://georgetown.box.com/s/19xdoy9e2bm3k3cpud28))

Since one should not edit `.sty` files, a `\xpatchcmd` can applied, kicking out the 'faulty' usage.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xtab}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

\usepackage{guthesis} % Style file for dissertation
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \pseudochapter{\listfigurename}}{}{}{}

\xpatchcmd{\listoftables}{%
  \pseudochapter{\listtablename}}{}{}{}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk}

\begin{abstract}
This dissertation examines blah blah
\end{abstract}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures  
\listoftables  


\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}  

\chapter{Introduction}
...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sinead-d: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!