# How to exclude list of figures and list of tables from table of contents?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, amsbook

My university doesn't provide me a template and I've used an external template from another university to write my final thesis. I've adding some useful things to improve the template and now I have a format issue.

I'm trying to exclude the line `List of Figures` and `List of Tables` from `Table of Contents`.

I've checked some previous questions but no one works for me [[1]](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1128) [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313254/excluding-list-of-figures-list-of-tables-from-the-table-of-contents-latex-re) and [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49721268/how-do-i-remove-the-list-of-figures-from-the-tables-of-contents-in-latex).

From link 1: when I tried to use tocbibind package, I have had a problem with tocbibind.sty (\tocchapter already defined)

From link 2: it uses a different template and I can't change it at this point this.

From Link 3: the use of an asterisk just at the end of \listoffigures and \listoftables does nothing (\listoffigures* , \listoftables* ).

My documentclass is an amsbook and this is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[openany, 11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
\usepackage{bookman}
\decimalpoint
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsgen,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{colortbl,longtable}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{parskip} % para separar párrafos con espacio.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1. } 
...
```

This is the document:

```
\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\input{content-chapter1.tex}
...
\input{content-chapterN.tex}
\appendix
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This answer to an earlier question may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123763 .  The relevant suggestion is the one for `\SkipTocEntry`; how it's defined depends on whether or not you're using `hyperref`.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. I've followed your links and It works!. `\SkipTocEntry` with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\gobblefour}[4]{}` was the key point.